# Delete all nodes of a binary search tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I have a binary search tree as in the code below. For example, in the beginning of the program I dynamically allocated memory for one instance of tree and for some nodes.

How can I properly delete all nodes and what destructors should I better write for that?

TreeNode.h:

```
class TreeNode {
private:
    unsigned __int64 _id;
    string _data;

public:
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;
    TreeNode *parent;

    TreeNode(const string &str);

    TreeNode();

    ~TreeNode();
};
```

TreeNode.cpp

```
TreeNode::TreeNode(const string &str) {
    left = nullptr;
    right = nullptr;
    parent = nullptr;
    _data = str;
    _id = (unsigned __int64)this;
    cout << "\n_id=" << _id << "; \"this\"=" << hex << this << dec << endl;
    cout << "Node initialized" << endl;

}

TreeNode::TreeNode() {
    left = nullptr;
    right = nullptr;
    parent = nullptr;
    _data = "";
    _id = (unsigned __int64)this;
}

TreeNode::~TreeNode() {
    //don't know how to implement
}
```

Tree.h:

```
class Tree {

public:
TreeNode *root;
    Tree();

    Tree(TreeNode *node);

    ~Tree();
};
```

Tree.cpp:

```
Tree::Tree() {
    root = nullptr;
}

Tree::Tree(TreeNode *node) {
    root = node;
}

Tree::~Tree() {
    //don't know how to implement
}
```

Comment: Which node should own `_left` and rightt? You're probably better of using `std::unique_ptr<Node>` and leave the cleanup to that class. BTW the `_` prefix is preserved for internal compiler implementation. Rather use a postfix `_`;

Comment: Draw your problem and see what you need to destroy and deallocate first. Normally in trees you go from leaves to the root to avoid leaving any dangling pointers.

Comment: You must go to the bottom of each branch and when go up then use [free](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/) on the pointer to that allocated memory space...

Comment: The TreeNodes really shouldn't have any destructor.  Let the Tree itself create and destroy the nodes as necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the nodes themselves, you are not allocating any memory for any member of a node so there's no need to have a destructor there. The default is enough.

Your actual tree destructor must take care of the pointers. Those occupy memory so they must be deleted. Your algorithm for taking care of each node should be the following:

- if the node has no children, it's a leaf node. Simply delete.
- if the node has **any** children, delete them.

This should be better done recursively with the help of a helper function called by Tree's destructor.